# Changing ownership of /root/boot

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

I need to access /boot so i can change a file continuously involving a PHP script ( To enable a raspberry pi and disable by changing start_x=' ' ) . However this involves me changing the permissions of boot.

I have tried sudo chown -R /boot and still get permissions denied when running as root. Also tried FTP and changing the folder of boot to let users modify content however this did not work either.

Is there anyway going around this???

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("config.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
[...]
?>
```

**Update:** I have tried to do chmod 775 /boot/config.txt and also symlink (ran successfully) so i have a shortcut in `/var/www/` however when trying to save the php script into `config.txt` (in www) still get permission denied even though that shortcut is set to 775. The issue still persists with changing to change the permission of the original file under `/boot` .

Comment: You could write a cron job that runs as root, checks for files in a place accessible to users, like a subdirectory of /tmp, and moves them from the deposited location to the secure location.

Comment: I would still get permission denied  since i would be overwriting the file

Comment: Is `/boot` a partition?  Often, it is. When you run `mount` by itself, no parameters, on the affected system, is `/boot` mounted read-write (rw) or read-only (ro)?

Comment: `/boot` part of  root in the raspberry pi. Basically i installed a package "raspistill"  which the data is stored under `/boot` , hence i need to edit one of the files

Comment: Become `root` and run `echo 123 > /boot/stackoverflowtest`.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: OK. So if you `ls /boot` there is now a `stackoverflowtest` file in there?  If so, there isn't a problem writing to `/boot`.

Comment: ~ When running `echo 123 /boot/stackoverflowtest`it echos what i typed however `echo 123  > /boot/stackoverflow test` no echo

Comment: Your first command writes both words to the screen.  The second command with the `>` writes  "123" to the file `/boot/stackoverflow`.  Since the second command did not give an error, the writing likely succeeded. You can print the file back out with `cat /boot/stackoverflow`.  It should have `123` in it.

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly, but how come i cannot overrwrite a file involving PHP then? It works perfectly on Windows 8 OS , i altered the destination to /boot/config.txt but receive permission denied still. Would this be a security issue with linux?

Comment: When PHP runs, it does not run as `root` because this would be a security hazard.   PHP runs under a special account.  Sometimes it is called `www`.  Somtimes it is `nobody`.  This account won't, and shouldn't be given, access to /boot.  What you need is a place that PHP can store files, and a program that runs as root that moves the files from there to where they specifically need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching a shell and trying your command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 123 >/boot/test"
```

works but

```
sudo echo 123 >/boot/test
```

fails. I don't understand the cause of this difference.

The user running as php would need permissions set in sudoers.d to execute the commands you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
sudo chown -R root /root/boot
```

Comment: Done this, still get permission denied even when running it in root O-o  Root does not contain a folder "boot" it's a partition i believe, so i have to to sudo chown -R pi /boot which doesnt work `operation not permitted` when doing `sudo chown -R pi /boot`

Comment: Try: `mount -o remount,gid=<pi's gid>,uid=<pi's uid> /boot` To determine pi's uid:

`cat /etc/passwd |grep pi`

To determine pi's gid:

`cat /etc/group |grep pi`

Comment: sorry, first time doing this i'm getting the result for pi's uid: `pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash` and for gid `adm:x:4:pi
dialout:x:20:pi
cdrom:x:24:pi
sudo:x:27:pi
audio:x:29:pi
www-data:x:33:pi,root
video:x:44:pi
plugdev:x:46:pi
games:x:60:pi
users:x:100:pi
pi:x:1000:
netdev:x:105:pi
input:x:999:pi
spi:x:1002:pi
gpio:x:1003:pi
` Which one should i type in

Comment: `mount -o remount,gid=1000,uid=1000 /boot`

Comment: Also if that up not success try umount and then mount device like this: `sudo umount /root/boot && sudo mount -t auto -o umask=000,dmask=000 /root/boot /media/USBHDD1`

Comment: Mounted and unmounted with `mount -o gid=1000,uid=1000 /boot` no success and the other command you provided didn't work since it does not have /media/USBHDD1

Comment: I think i might have to change my idea and create a python script as such and save it under /boot with root access and a symlink to /var/www so when run via php it will edit the file - hopefully.

Comment: but you should change this ` /media/USBHDD1` with your device

Comment: It's alright, i managed to fix it :) Thanks for the tip about mounting and unmounting, i shall do this in the future

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs under a restricted account and can't write anything in the boot partition.

You might be able to add the account PHP runs as to the sudoers file, although it's a pretty huge security risk.